# background color is not working in Mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I am in a design issue please help me to find a solution. 
[here is my page](http://australian.dk.linux84.wannafindserver.dk/)
This is working fine in Google chrome but `background-color: transparent;` in header is not working on Mozilla and IE and it shows a white background on my header.

I have tried by giving `position:static` but is not working for me.
please help me.

Comment: I have added a background image to my header. There is a white background to this image in FF and IE

Comment: Sorry that was a typing mistake... updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `overflow: hidden` to your `#header_main` class and it eliminates the issue.

So.. it would look like this:

```
#header_main{
z-index: 1;
border-top: 3px solid #FFF;
background: url("http://australian.webeteerprojects.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/header-back.png") no-repeat scroll center top / 100% 100%       transparent;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: when adding this style the top portion of my logo also will be miss. any solution???

Answer (score -3):

another solution could be to fake the background and create a 1px transparent gif:

```
background:url(transparent.gif);
```

Comment: not at all, but unfortunately i haven't an IE here to test it :S

Comment: i deleted the rgba idea.

Comment: background-color and background would also make no difference here